# Как сделать редирект со всех страниц с цифрами в ЧПУ на такие де без цифр?

Tags: редирект

Как сделать редирект со всех страниц, которые содержат цифры в начале последней части URL (ЧПУ) на такой же URL без цифр?

Пример:

```
/category/category/20-page.html
/category/30-page.html
/40-page.html
```

перенаправить на:

```
/category/category2/page.html
/category/page.html
/page.html
```

Буду благодарен если кто подскажет решение через htaccess